# Android app freezing and causing ANR

Tags: android

I am getting ANR on my application and it freezes the app, when I pulled out `anr/traces.txt` I see the ANR is thrown by this:

```
InputDispatcher" prio=10 tid=22 MONITOR
     | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41b49f78 self=0x5f584d98
     | sysTid=547 nice=-8 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=1599621384
     | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=42 stm=86 core=0
     at    com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.inputDispatchingTimedOut(ActivityManagerService.java:~8670)
  - waiting to lock <0x419b0d38> (a com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService) held by tid=8 (Binder_1)
  at com.android.server.am.ActivityRecord.keyDispatchingTimedOut(ActivityRecord.java:968)
  at com.android.server.am.ActivityRecord$Token.keyDispatchingTimedOut(ActivityRecord.java:310)
  at com.android.server.wm.InputMonitor.notifyANR(InputMonitor.java:132)
  at com.android.server.input.InputManagerService.notifyANR(InputManagerService.java:1297)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

How do I fix this issue.

Comment: Key dispatching has a watchdog timer-  if you take too long to finish it will cause an ANR.  What are you doing that's taking so long, and can it be pushed off to a later time or another thread?

Comment: I had a videoscreen saver running over night and then in morning i saw this ANR.